# Is it a common practice to use public enum for containing default constants in c++?

Tags: c++, enums

I'm a beginner in c++ with some Java background. I came cross this piece of sample code

```
class simple_cbuf { 
public:
    enum { default_size = 100; };
    explicit simple_cbuf(size_t size =
                         default_size);
    ~simple_cbuf();
    size_t size() const;
    bool   empty() const;
    int    top() const; /* see below */
    void   pop();
    void   push(int new_value);
  private:
    /* whatever you want */
};
```

It seems to me that this code is using a public enum to hold the default size of the buffer. Is it a common practice in c++? In Java I would make this a "private static final int" constant

Comment: Meh, that's just a coding style / personal preference thing. It certainly could be a `static const int` somewhere.

Comment: Or the default value could just be mentoned as the default argument directly.

Comment: The nice thing about unnamed, unscoped enums is that they are guaranteed to take no space, and never requires a separate definition. (If it is a `static const int` and you pass it to a function taking a `const int &`, that counts as an odr-use and you need a definition; if it's an unscoped enumerator the compiler will just initialize a temporary `int` for that.)

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the explanation! But I don't get why unnamed, unscoped enums takes no space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly common practice, to make sure a constant is really treated as a constant in all cases.

What C++ has a lot, that Java doesn't, is references to any type, even primitive types, and as a result of that,

```
struct S {
  static const int i = 3;
};
void f(const int &);
void g() { f(S::i); };
```

doesn't behave like how many want it to behave: it doesn't take the value of `S::i`, store that in a temporary object, and pass that object to `f`. Instead, passes a reference directly to `S::i` straight to `f`.

This sounds good, but can cause surprising problems where you wouldn't realise you really need a definition of `S::i`, to make sure its address can be resolved.

`enum` avoids that: after `enum { i = 3 };`, `i` is an rvalue, and its address cannot be taken. `f(i);` would be valid, and would pass a temporary object to `f`.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ `static const int` is equivalent to `static final int` in java .
If you use c++11, it can be `static constexpr int` to make sure a constant is always treated as a constant.

Enum is better when you have a few related values.

Answer (score 0):

Since `size()` returns a `size_t`, for consistency, you can do something like this:

```
size_t default_size() const noexcept
{
   return 100;
}
```

Comment: This should be a static method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class simple_cbuf { 
public:
    enum { 
           default_size = 100, 
           expanded_size = 150,
           abridged_size = 50
    };
    explicit simple_cbuf(size_t size =
                     default_size);
    ~simple_cbuf();
    size_t size() const;
    bool   empty() const;
    int    top() const; /* see below */
    void   pop();
    void   push(int new_value);
private:
    /* whatever you want */
};
```

This code could be an example of why you would want to use an enum, and that `private static final int` can directly relate to `static const int`. The case you described isn't usual, but works.